# NodeJS Express. res.send() fails when assigned to another var

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Express v3.4.4. When i try to do like this:

```
var cb = res.send;
cb(result);
```

I get an error:

```
   ...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:84
   var HEAD = 'HEAD' == req.method;
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
```

In code, working one:

```
    workflow.on('someEvent', function () {
      res.send({
          error: null,
          result: 'Result'
        });
    });
```

not working:

```
    workflow.on('someEvent', function () {
      var cb = res.send; 
      cb({
          error: null,
          result: 'Result'
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `send` is actually a function of the object `res`. It tries to use other data from the `res` object. But, when you do

```
var cb = res.send;
cb({...});
```

you are simply using the function object `send` without the reference to the `res` object. That is why it is not working.

---

If you ever need to do something like that, then bind the `res` object to the `send` function like this

```
var cb = res.send.bind(res);
```

now

```
cb({...});
```

will also work. Because the `res` is bound to the `send` function object and the resulting function is stored in `cb`.

The `bind` function actually is [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @RayonDabre Exactly. That is why we need to explicitly bind it, if it is ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the fact that in JavaScript the value of `this` inside a method is bound to the containing object.

- Calling `res.send()` makes the value of `this` inside the `send` function to be `res`.
- In contrast, calling the *unbound* version `cb()` the value of `this` is not what is expected.

The internal implementation of Express.js relies on the fact that `this` is bound and most likely contains an expression such as `this.method` that causes the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined` error.

Comment: I strongly disagree with `the value of this is undefined`

Comment: @RayonDabre yep, oops, you're right, answered too quickly